# When was the phrase "sufficiently smart compiler" first used?

Tags: history, programming, terminology

In discussions and arguments about programming language design, one often hears comments about "sufficiently smart" compilers, as in "X needn't be inefficient, since a sufficiently smart compiler should be able to optimize it well".

As far as I know, the term originated within the Lisp community, since compiling Lisp into efficient object code is notoriously difficult (though not impossible, by any means). But what is the earliest known use of the phrase? [Here's one from 1986](https://cl-su-ai.cddddr.org/msg03457.html), but surely earlier instances exist:

> I think that one documentation string is enough, the rest can be
> ignored by any sufficiently smart compiler given the semantics of the
> language, and anyone who builds a really nice Commmon Lisp environment
> is welcome to extend the notion of documentation strings to include
> multiple ones.

(Incidentally, that message suggests that "`...`" be made a special identifier that is syntactically valid but signals an error when evaluated, to mark unimplemented code. This exact functionality would be added to Perl in version 5.12 from 2010.)

I am also interested (to a lesser extent) in early documents expressing the same sentiment with similar wording, if not the specific phrasing.

Comment: @LeoB. I agree that it's more of a linguistics question. It would be better suited for a general "History of computing" site.

Comment: @texdr.aft: Retrocomputing SE de facto *is* a history of computing site: see e.g. https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16 and https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/459/

Comment: As a developer--I would guess that a phrase to this effect was probably used sometime between coming up with the idea of a compiler and actually implementing the first one.

Comment: I'm uncertain about the *first* use, but references to a sufficiently smart compiler were practically the mantra of the Common Lisp committee.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The phrase

> In some cases a sufficiently smart compiler could figure out some of
> these precedence relationships.

was used in the 1979 book:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780120441204500088

Chapter 3 - SIMSCRIPT: PAST, PRESENT, AND SOME THOUGHTS ABOUT THE FUTURE
HARRY M.MARKOWITZ

Indicating that it predated Steele, and also that it started as "sufficiently smart" not "sufficiently advanced" - indicating that it wasn't influenced by Clarke.

The phrase

> This is the sort of thing that we might imagine a sufficiently advanced compiler being able to do, but we might not be willing to pay for the overhead needed to deduce the information.

was used in 1984 in The Description of Large Systems by Kent Pitman
(might be same influence as Steele.)

https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a148072.pdf

(Found by google scholar.)

Comment: Pitman and Steele were friends and may even have worked together, so they also likely influenced each other.

Comment: Here is a "webbed" version of Pitman's paper: http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Large-Systems.html

Comment: @Barmar - thanks for the note. I noticed that Pitman worked with AI at MIT so I found it likely, but it's nice to have more information.

Answer (score 11):

The phrase ***any sufficiently advanced/smart/etc X*** in a technology context stems from (in other words, is a [snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) of) the Arthur C. Clarke's quote “Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic” (<del>1962</del> 1973).

Comment: Are you sure it does and if yes, what proof is there to support that? Or are you pointing a possible origin were it _may_  be based on?

Comment: @Raffzahn I am sure that it is a snowclone because it matches the earlier attested pattern. Whether any given quote is an following of the pattern or not, may be arguable (although the latter is unlikely as the Clarke's quote was widely known, thus even if unintended, it would be subconscious), but there is little point in that as the linguistic novelty of the phrase in question is minimal and it could have been uttered innumerable times in the course of discussions related to programming language design in the late 60s or all of the 70s.

Comment: Leo, I'm all with you. My point here is that the way you wrote it _("The phrase [...] stems from [...] the Arthur C. Clarke's quote")_ makes it sound like a sure fact, not just a quite likely one.

Comment: But it doesn't fit the pattern: Clarke's law is "Any sufficiently advanced X is indistinguishable from Y."; and both it and its snowclones have "X" as something good and "Y" as something that isn't that good. If it had been "Any sufficiently advanced compiler is indistinguishable from an adversary"; I would have agreed but not in this case.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke didn’t coin the word ‘sufficiently’.

Comment: Kind of ironic if you consider for some problems compilers intelligent enough don't exist after decades when most though they would be real by now. We are left with magic tricks.

Comment: Did Arthur C. Clarke write that quote in 1962? Wikipedia is contradictory and also states that it came in 1973
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke's_three_laws and reading the alleged origin "Hazards of prophecy" I see similar themes but not the quote (the 1st law is present though).

Comment: @HansOlsson [My source](http://lab.cccb.org/en/arthur-c-clarke-any-sufficiently-advanced-technology-is-indistinguishable-from-magic/)

Comment: @LeoB But that is a secondary source, and I tried to look at something which I believe is closer to the primary source, http://www.sfcenter.ku.edu/Sci-Tech-Society/stored/futurists_hazards_of_prophecy.pdf  The 1st law is present, but not the others, even if there are allusions to them.

Comment: @HansOlsson Searching for "Profiles of the Future: An Inquiry into the Limits of the Possible" mentioned in the source link reveals that [it was published in 1962](https://www.amazon.com/Profiles-Future-Inquiry-Limits-Possible/dp/0575402776) and that [it contains the quote](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/163451-profiles-of-the-future)

Comment: Yes it was published then, but the 3rd law was added later in a revised version in 1973 so the two facts cannot be combined like that; http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/eng/Clarke's_Third_Law https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Clarke's+Third+Law https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-clarkes-laws-2699067

Comment: The problem is that "sufficiently" is not a sufficiently rare modifier that it provides much evidence that this is a snowclone. Most of the people in the Lisp world at the time had training in mathematical logic and would have been sufficiently familiar with phrases like "sufficiently strong axiomatic system" (e.g. often used in discussing Gödel's results) that it seems like a bit of a stretch to bring Clarke into it.

Comment: @JohnColeman Then it is quite peculiar that the phrase has not been attested for the first 15 years of Lisp, before the coinage of the Clarke's quote, but it only took 6 years after that, isn't it?

Comment: @LeoB. The point is that "sufficiently smart compiler" is a perfectly *natural* phrase, and not one which clearly echoes Clarke. It might be the case that the person who first used the phrase was familiar with and influenced by the Clarke quote, but you have presented no compelling evidence of it. I suggested an alternative explanation that strikes me as being as plausible as yours. I am not convinced that my explanation is any more than a (weak) hunch. But -- you seem to think that your explanation *is* more than a hunch.

Answer (score 8):

The Evolution of Lisp, an outline of the history, traces the phrase back to 1984.  See page 42.

https://www.scribd.com/document/62651058/The-Evolution-of-Lisp

Comment: A more accessible source is page 24 of https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/331/resources/papers/Evolution-of-Lisp.pdf